# VBA - Use countifs function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some issues using the countifs function inside VBA. It keeps throwing me the following message:

"Run-time error '438':

Object doesn't support this property or method"

The code is as follows:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row), Range("I:I"), Range("I" & row)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row)) Then

Material = Workbooks(macroexcel).Worksheets("Data").Range("I" & row).Value
Qty = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("J:J"), Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row), Range("I:I"), Material)
Else
(...)
End if
```

Do you have any idea why VBA is throwing this error?

Thanks

Comment: You need to read up on the Countifs method as you appear to have missed out critical bits.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easier than I thought: the "application." part should be deleted.

so, instead of

```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row), Range("I:I"), Range("I" & row)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row))
```

it should say

```
  If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row), Range("I:I"), Range("I" & row)) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("N:N"), Range("N" & row))
```